# How to print in google chrome from android with html?

Tags: javascript, android, twitter-bootstrap

This command works in firefox,internet explorer, and chrome for windows and seems like a common answer `onClick="print();"`.  I am using bootstrap and not sure what this won't print from an android tablet (Nothing appears or pops up for printing only on the tablet).

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg col-md-12 col-xs-12" value="Print List" onClick="print();"  />
```

Comment: Note that Android only got a printing framework as of Android 4.4, so older devices are unlikely to support printing from browsers.

Comment: I am using android 4.2, so that is probably why.  Is there something they have to download on android for it?  Maybe some kind of cloud print I would guess.

Comment: I have no idea what Android browsers would integrate with Google Cloud Print on older devices, though that is certainly worth trying.